# Python 3 except TypeError not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please kindly note I am new to this. Your help will be appreciated.

```
while True:
    user = str(input('Enter users sex:'))
    try:
        if user == 'female' or user == 'male': break
    except TypeError:
        print('Please enter male or female')
    continue
print('The user is:',user)
```

I do not understand when an integer is entered the

```
except TypeError:
    print('Please enter male or female')
```

does not `print('Please enter male or female')` and ask the user for input.

Comment: Because the `try` itself doesn't fail. You can convert an integer to its string representation just fine, it just won't equal `female` or `male`.

Comment: Hint: `str(3)` does not throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: I think the simple answer to your question is that if the user enters an integer (say, 5) you won't get back an `int` from `input` but instead you will get `"5"` which is a `str` itself.

Comment: FWIW, there's no actual _harm_ in passing the string returned from `input()` to `str()`: you just get back the original string object. But it's an unnecessary step so it just adds clutter to the code.

Comment: In addition to the helpful answers already posted. I suggest that you read more about exceptions. What you are attempting to do here is not a proper use of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually don't need an exception check here. Also, your conditional statement will not raise that `TypeError`. Instead, simply use your conditional statement to continue your loop. This will also not require you to have to use any `continue` statement here either.

Furthermore, all `input` calls will return a *string*, so you do not need to cast as such. So, simply take your input without the `str` call:

```
while True:
    user = input('Enter users sex:')
    if user == 'female' or user == 'male':
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter male or female')
print('The user is:', user)
```

If you were putting this in to a function, you can simply return your final result once satisfied and then print the "result" of what that function returns. The following example will help illustrate this:

```
def get_user_gender():
    while True:
        user = str(input('Enter users sex:'))
        if user == 'female' or user == 'male':
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter male or female')
    return 'The user is: {}'.format(user)


user_gender = get_user_gender()
print(user_gender)
```

Small note, you will notice I introduced the `format` string method. It makes manipulating strings a bit easier getting in to the habit with dealing with your string manipulation/formatting in this way.

Comment: Isn't the result of `input` a string in Python 3, so you don't technically need to cast it as one?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, that is true. I didn't quite catch that being done. Thanks. I'll update my answer to explain that.

Comment: @idjaw if i wanted this to be a function, will adding :

`def usergender():
while True:
    user = input('Enter users sex:')
    if user == 'female' or user == 'male':
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter male or female')
print('The user is:', user)`

Be enough?

Comment: @idjaw Thank you sincerely for explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns a string in Python 3. Calling `str` on it leaves it as it is, so it will never raise an exception.

You could get an error if you tried to do something like:

```
number = int(input("enter a number: "))

enter a number: abc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ec0ea39b1c6c> in <module>()
----> 1 number = int(input("enter a number: "))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

because the string 'abc' can't be converted to an integer (in base 10, at least...)

Comment: I guess it's worth noting that this throws a `ValueError` not a `TypeError` and wouldn't be caught in the original code because the conversion was outside of the `try`/`except` block anyway.

Comment: Oh, that's right, I hadn't noticed that the `try/except` block only included the `if` - which never could have caused an exception.

Comment: Good answer, but I think it belongs to a different question. ;)